# Need the ability to override the metadata of specific instance of a class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, overriding, metadata

I am looking for any possible solutions to override existing class's metadata type.

For example:

```
public class PersonMetadata 
{   
  [Required]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  [DisplayName("First Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-mm-dd}")]
  public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

public class OtherPersonMetadata : PersonMetadata 
{
  [DisplayName("Full Name")]
  public new string Name { get; set; }

  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-mm-yyyy}")]
  public new DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetadata))]
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeRecord 
{
  public Person PersonA { get; set; }

  [ApplyMetaData(typeof(OtherPersonMetadata))] <----- Possible & How?
  public Person PersonB { get; set; }
}
```

Can PersonB use OtherPersonMetadata? Any thoughts? Thanks - J

---

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetadata))]
Person{
...
}

Class EmplyeeRecord{
    Person PersonA -> PersonMetaData
    Person PersonB -> OtherMetaData
}
```

Any chance I can override PersonB's metadata in this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here.  Are you trying to apply attributes not to a property, but to an object instance?  Attributes apply to code, not to instances.

Comment: Are you trying to do mixins? You're wanting to add `Id`, `Name` and `Birthday` as properties on the `Person` instance, but only for `PersonB`?

Comment: Hmm..I need find out a way to use different properties (they are same class) to use different metadata.

Comment: @jeef3 yes sth like that, basically I want PersonB to use another metadata